# What is the geometry of $SU(2)$? How do representations change this?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Physicist here! I have been studying $SU(2)$ and I have a few questions in regards to thinking about the group itself.

Consider the Lie group $SU(2)$.

One way to think about $SU(2)$ as a manifold is the set of unit quaternions, that is, $S^3$.

Q1: If we consider elements of $SU(2)$ as transformations, is there a way to visualize this transformation on the manifold?

We know, from representation theory, that we can find $n$-dimensional representations of $SU(2)$.

Q2: How does our view of the Lie Group changes when we deal with a different representation other than the "usual one" that is the 2D representation? That is, if we use the 10 dimensional representation of $SU(2)$, do we still think of the manifold as being $S^3$?

Q3: What can we say about the geometry of SU(2)? Does it change when we study it in light of a different representation of the group?

Thanks!

Comment: Given $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, the conjugation action of  the quaternion $\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)(ai+bj+ck)$ on $S^3$ is rotation through $2\theta$ about the plane spanned by $1,  (ai+bj+ck)$.  Presumably though you want the left multiplication action, rather than the conjugation action.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Before visualizing, you have to tell us **the** action and **the** manifold on which the group is acting. As for **the** geometry of the group $SU(2)$, do you mean **the** topology of this group? This does not depend on the representation.

Comment: Each of those representations you mention (excluding the trivial rep) are embeddings of $SU(2)$ as a submanifold of some $GL(n)$. So we aren't changing any intrinsic geometric things by choosing a different embedding but you could, in theory, study the extrinsic geometry of the embeddings themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Yes/no/maybe: Give me an action of $SU(2)$ by transformations (of what kind?) on (what space?) and depending on the complexity of the situation I may or may not be able to do a visualization.

Q2: A Lie group $G$ (in your case, $G=SU(2)$) should be treated as a primary object here and it does not change (as a Lie group) if we consider a different representation. Accordingly, the underlying smooth manifold will not change either. A physical analogy would be, say, an electron: You can place it in a different environment which may change, say, its energy, but it will remain an electron.

Q3: It depends. One can put different geometries on $SU(2)$. Some of these will be intrinsic (independent of the group action), some may be extrinsic (depending on the action). The standard example of intrinsic geometry is the biinvariant Riemannian metric given by, say, the Killing form on the Lie algebra. An example of an extrinsic geometry is the **chordal metric** given by the identification of $SU(2)$ and the unit sphere in ${\mathbb C}^2$.